# Find out how often a value is between 2 dates in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi with the follow code I request what dates are all in my database without duplicates.
Then I save it to an array. In the array I also need an other value.

The value I need is how much users are in one day in the database without duplicates.
For Example the array must later lookslike 23.07.2013 - 10, 24.07.2013 - 50 (users).
I search for several hours but I don't find a good mysql query.

```
$query = "SELECT id, user, timestamp FROM stat WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '$datum1' AND '$datum2' GROUP BY timestamp";
$result = mysql_query($query,$db);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        mysql_num_rows($result);
        $dataset1[] = array(strtotime($row['timestamp']),$number_of_users_on_this_day);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're getting vs what you want, but it seems like you could could get the number of users without duplicates by doing `SELECT DISTINCT(user) WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '$datum1' AND '$datum2';`  and if you're only concerned with periods of whole days you can employ LEFT(timestamp, 10) to break your data down by day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

> $query = "SELECT id, user, COUNT(*) as count FROM stat WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '$datum1' AND '$datum2' GROUP BY timestamp";

This will return the number of entries in the value 'count'

if you want distinct data, in place of * use

> COUNT(DISTINCT id)

with whatever field you want to be unique in place of 'id'